# Drawing line or polygon interactively in ArcMap and later saving it as shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mxd, arcgis-10.4, graphics

I am using ArcGIS 10.4 for Desktop.

I need to draw line feature in current mapdocument interactively and later save it for further analysis such as stack profile so that I can do the stack profile generation interactively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - see [Understanding converting between graphics and features](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/converting-between-graphics-and-features-about-con.htm) in the Help:

> You can convert graphics you draw on your map into shapefiles or
>   geodatabase feature classes. The Convert Graphics To Features command,
>   which is available from the Drawing menu on the Draw toolbar or by
>   right-clicking a data frame in the table of contents, supports all the
>   graphic types you can draw with the tools in the graphics palette on
>   the Draw toolbar, including circles, curved lines, and freehand lines.
>   You can also convert graphic text into annotation feature classes.